# My laptop screen sometimes displays different colors

Tags: display

Two weeks ago, I dropped my laptop.

When I open up (start), on some areas of the screen the color has changed (different contrast).

Later I dropped my laptop again, and the problem seemed to be fixed.

Now when I close the screen of my laptop, and later I open up laptop the problem appears again.

I think it may be a problem with a cable connected with the screen so that when I close the laptop and open it again maybe a cable has become loose (uncoupled).

How can I diagnose/resolve this issue?

Comment: I've made some edits to your question that I think clarify the problem that you are having. Please review the edits to make sure that your question is still the same question you wanted to ask.

Comment: Please add the make and model of your laptop.

Comment: Msi cr500x, do u know price of used display 15.6, i wanna buy?

Comment: https://forum-en.msi.com/moderator/assembly-guides/ms-1683-disassemble-sop.pdf might help you.

Comment: https://forum-en.msi.com/faq/article/cr600 links apply to cr500 as well

Answer (score 1):

I think you've basically answered this one yourself already. You'll need to find a 'tear-down' of your laptop model which will guide you through the process of taking it apart in order to access the cable for the screen.

It would also be worth reseating your RAM too.

Comment: I've fixed many a laptop (mostly Lenovo's, for some reason) that needed the cable on the back of the screen attached tightly. It is not uncommon for them to get flaky, then work for awhile, then get flaky again and it's not unusual for "thumping" the screen to temporarily fix it.